# If object set has an object property create an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a response value which is dynamic which i need to store in redux state,

Response consist of array of object and and name
ex :

```
{data:[
 {name:"abc",age:"10",id:"10"}
 {name:"abc",age:"15",id:"20"}
 {name:"def",age:"15",id:"20"}
 ]
 name: "abc"
}
```

So if the name is same I need to create array with the name.

Expected :

```
abc:[
   {name:"abc",age:"10",id:"10"}
   {name:"abc",age:"15",id:"20"}
]
```

something I tried

```
data.map(function(o) {
       if(data.name ==o.name)
        return name[o];
 });
```

Comment: as I understood your question , you want to create an array of objects with the same property as the name property in the response object?

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter()` is all you need

Comment: Yes which I need to store in state

Comment: The callback of `Array.prototype.map()` is supposed to return something for _every_ element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting a new object with a `key` of the `name property` you could try something like this

```js
const response = {
  data: [{
      name: "abc",
      age: "10",
      id: "10"
    },
    {
      name: "abc",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
    {
      name: "def",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
  ],
  name: "abc"
}

const createSet = (someData) => {
  let key = someData.name
  let data = someData.data.filter(e => e.name === key)
  return {
    [key]: data
  }
}

console.log(createSet(response))
```

Comment: i have extended my question here with your reply  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75003100/save-in-redux-data-as-array-of-object-in-state-and-update-state-if-state-has-pre

Answer (score 1):

You can extract duplicated using `reduce` and `filter` :

```js
var data = {
data:[
 {name:"abc",age:"10",id:"10"},
 {name:"abc",age:"15",id:"20"},
 {name:"def",age:"15",id:"20"}
 ],
 name: "abc"
}

const lookup = data.data.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.name] = ++a[e.name] || 0;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(data.data.filter(e => lookup[e.name]));
```

Comment: I have extended question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75003100/save-in-redux-data-as-array-of-object-in-state-and-update-state-if-state-has-pre