# Save in redux data as array of object in state and update state if state has previous state available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux

I receive my Response as the below format example

```
const response = {
  data: [{
      name: "abc",
      age: "10",
      id: "10"
    },
    {
      name: "def",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
  ],
  name: "abc"
}
```

I want to save it in my redux state is, if the response.name and property name matches and save it as an array of object.
The response.name is abc and object has name abc

Expected state

```
"abc": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "age": "10",
      "id": "10"
    },
  ]
```

Case 2
I receive a new Response with a new object abc with a different id and age with response.name same abc,

```
const response = {
  data: [{
      name: "abc",
      age: "10",
      id: "10"
    },
    {
      name: "abc",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
    {
      name: "def",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
  ],
  name: "abc"
}
```

I need to update if a new object set is present in the state

```
"abc": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "age": "10",
      "id": "10"
    },
    {
      name: "abc",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    }
  ]
```

Case 3
Now I receive a new response with a different response name response.name = "def"

```
const response = {

  data: [{
      name: "abc",
      age: "10",
      id: "10"
    },
    {
      name: "def",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
  ],
  name: "def"
}
```

Here def is the response.name , so I need to create a new array of objects like the below :

```
"def": [
    {
      "name": "def",
      "age": "15",
      "id": "10"
    },
  ]
```

and My state should be having both

```
data : [
"abc": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "age": "10",
      "id": "10"
    },
]
"def": [
    {
      "name": "def",
      "age": "15",
      "id": "10"
    },
  ]
]
```

With the below code, i tried it replaces the old state

```
const initialUserState = {
    arr:[]
}

export default function userState(state = initialUserState, action)
{
    let response = action.payload;
    console.log(arr);
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case ADD_ITEM: 
             const createSet = (someData) => {
             let key = someData.name
             let data = someData.data.filter(e => e.name === key)
                 return {
                 [key]: data
                }
             }
            console.log(createSet(response))
           let createdArray = createSet(response);
            return { 
                      arr[createdArray];
                   }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, And preserve previous

Comment: I have done the change, But how I can check my Case2 point  here ?                                  Case 2 I receive a new Response with a new object abc with a different id and age with response.name same abc,

Comment: I cant add the response call here , just one issue I have is if same array name it must update not create new array with same name, if abc array already exist dont create new again, need to update with upcoming response value

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a look :

```js
const response = {
  data: [{
      name: "abc",
      age: "10",
      id: "10"
    },
    {
      name: "abc",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
    {
      name: "def",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
    {
      name: "def",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
  ],
  name: "abc"
}

const response2 = {

  data: [{
      name: "abc",
      age: "10",
      id: "10"
    },
    {
      name: "def",
      age: "15",
      id: "20"
    },
  ],
  name: "def"
}

var state = {};
function getState(response) {
  let lookup = response.data.reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e.name] = (response.name == e.name) || 0;
    return a;
  }, {});
  
  state[response.name] = response.data.filter(e => lookup[e.name]);
}

getState(response);
getState(response2);
console.log(state);
```

Comment: But here its local state, but when coming to redux state it creating new array even if array exists @SelVazi

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of things here that seem unnecessary.
If you only want to add an item, add an item. No filtering etc. needed.

```js
export default function userState(state = initialUserState, action) {
  let response = action.payload;
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return {
        // assuming that what you want to add is `action.payload`
        arr: state.arr.concat(action.payload),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

That said, all of this is an **extremely outdated (pre-2019) style of Redux that you should not be writing today**. Modern Redux does not have `switch..case` reducers, action type constants like `ADD_TYPE` and no need for immutable reducer logic.
Please take the time and read up on [modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and take the time to follow [the official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Comment: It will just add up into array, I want it to be formatted before passing to state. The above solution just push that data and it just adds up, Maybe you not got my question properly. @phry

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had just seen the bottom of your question. You never show how a full state should actually look like, so it is very hard to give you a conclusive answer here. Please add a full state snapshot, not only a part. The more important message still stands though: you are using a very outdated style of Redux that you should not be using since 2019. Doing something like this will be a lot of hard-readable code in the immutable style and a lot less (and more readable) code in the modern `createSlice` style.